# Access Method result in If statement

Tags: java

Is it possible to access the result of a method statement in an If statement?  I'm writing a program to calculate a meter reading assignment. Netbeans states it cannot find the symbol of the methodName I created. Here is the code so far:

```
public class Meter_Utility {

//Begin Main Method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//create new scanner object

    //Declarations
    double prevMeter;
    double currMeter;
    double rate = 0;
//        double totalUsage = 0;

    //obtain meter readings from user
    System.out.print("Welcome to the City Power Bill Calculator! Please enter your previous meter reading: ");
    prevMeter = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter your Current meter reading: ");
    currMeter = input.nextDouble();

    //output total usage
    System.out.printf("your usage was: %.1f KwHs", totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter));

    //calculate rate        
    if (totalUsage < 500) {
        rate = .0809;
    }
    else if (totalUsage > 500 && totalUsage < 900){
        rate = .091;
    }
    else {
        rate = .091;
    }

    //output rate   
    System.out.printf("\nYour rate was: %.4f/KwH", rate);

} //End Main Method  

/**
 *  Method to calculate total Usage
 * @param u1
 * @param u2
 * @return difference of month 1 and month 2
 */
private static double totalUsage(double u1, double u2) {
    return u2 - u1;
}
```

}

So I would like totalUsage to be accessible in the if statement, that way I can determine the rate and carry on.

I researched on stackoverflow already for a similar posts and came up empty. I researched here: for the if/else statements already as well:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: The variable `totalUsage` does not exist. It is commented out, hence the `Cannot find symbol` message. The method `totalUsage(double u1, double u2)` is irrelevant as it is never used.

Comment: Or you have to add the brackets and the arguments if you want to reference the function

Comment: Actually, I see now that `totalUsage(double u1, double u2)` is actually used, so I was wrong there - but the issue is still that you are trying to check the value of the variable `totalUsage` with for example `if(totalUsage < 500)`, which is not possible because the variable does not exist.

Comment: Add `double totalusage = totalusage(prevMeter, currentmeter)` before the system.out

Comment: Ah yes, I remember now. I commented it out and was trying another approach. When uncommented, regardless of the input result (less than 500, more than 900, etc) it calculates everything at the .0809 rate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare a variable to stock your total usage, or call the method each time.

**With a variable :**

```
double totalUsage = totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter);
System.out.printf("your usage was: %.1f KwHs", totalUsage);

//calculate rate        
if (totalUsage < 500.0) {
    rate = .0809;
}
else if (totalUsage > 500.0 && totalUsage < 900.0){
    rate = .091;
}
else {
    rate = .091;
}

//output rate   
System.out.printf("\nYour rate was: %.4f/KwH", rate);
```

**By calling method :**

```
//output total usage
System.out.printf("your usage was: %.1f KwHs", totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter));

//calculate rate        
if (totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter) < 500.0) {
    rate = .0809;
}
else if (totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter) > 500.0 && totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter) < 900.0){
    rate = .091;
}
else {
    rate = .091;
}

//output rate   
System.out.printf("\nYour rate was: %.4f/KwH", rate);
```

Comment: Perfect! so I can access it, I just need to call the full method format it sounds like... Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ah and I see where you are storing it in the double totalUsage = totalUsage(prevMeter, currMeter);